# Неверный вывод времени js

Tags: javascript, jquery, время

Я получаю данные из json-файла. Они имеют вид массива обьектов(это сообщения).

```
[
    {
        "time": "1499882893",
        "user": "qwe",
        "message": "q"
    },
    {
        "time": "1499882894",
        "user": "qwe",
        "message": "w"
    },
    {
        "time": "1499882895",
        "user": "qwe",
        "message": "e"
    }
]
```

(«time» в секундах)

Скрипт должен отображать только сообщения за последний час. Он делает это, но время, отображаемое на экране, неверно.

Это должно работать примерно так: пользователь переходит на страницу, он видит сообщения за последний час, он переписывается, а на экране отображаются все новые сообщения.

Но я получаю так, что сообщения за последний час показываются с неправильным временем(где то ошибка в обработке времени обратно в читаемый вариант) и, кроме того, вывод сообщений не правильный ибо при загрузке сообщений с из файла(если прошло меньше часа) загрузятся все сообщения, даже если они и были загружены ранее.

Сообщения отображаются в последний час, но мне нужно, чтобы новые сообщения отображались сразу и не отображались, если они уже были показаны (как сейчас)

```js
callback([{
    "time": "1499882893",
    "user": "qwe",
    "message": "q"
  },
  {
    "time": "1499882894",
    "user": "qwe",
    "message": "w"
  },
  {
    "time": "1499882895",
    "user": "qwe",
    "message": "e"
  }
]);

function callback(respond) {
  setTimeout(function tick() {
    for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
      var data = respond[i];
      var now = Date.now();
      var diff_time = Math.floor(now - ((data.time) * 1000));
      if (diff_time <= 3600000) {
        var new_date = new Date(diff_time);
        var res = [new_date.getHours(), new_date.getMinutes(), new_date.getSeconds()].map(function(x) {
          return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
        }).join(":");
        var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');
        $('#messages').append(rowClone);
        $('.time', rowClone).html(res);
        $('.name', rowClone).html(data.user);
        $('.message', rowClone).html(data.message);
        $('.scroller').scrollTop($('#messages').height());
      }
    }
    setTimeout(tick, 3600000);
  }, 1);
}
```

```css
.scroller {
  width: 490px;
  height: 255px;
  max-height: 255px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table#messages {
  min-height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fffecd;
  border: none;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

tr {
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
}

td.time,
td.name {
  width: 70px;
  max-width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

td.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form#text_submit {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

input#text {
  width: 370px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #fffecd;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

input#submit {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 21px;
  margin-top: 21px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 95px;
  background: #635960;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time"></td>
      <td class="name"></td>
      <td class="message"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<form method="POST" id="easyForm">
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Итак, у меня есть два небольших вопроса:

1.Когда мы нашли `diff_time` стоит условие, если оно меньше 3600000 то код выполняется(выполняется запись). Но я пытаюсь вывести разницу вместо того что бы вывести само время сообщения.Как реализовать цикл для всех тех `diff_time`которые меньше 3600000 что бы выводило их время?

2.Как я могу сделать проверку: было ли уже загружено это сообщение?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что когда вы делаете дату из таймстампа, таймстамп считается по гринвичу, а получившаяся дата - в локальной таймзоне. В итоге, вы хотели посчитать разницу между двумя таймстампами, а получили непонятно откуда взявшиеся 4 часа) Чтобы такого не было, при относительных расчетах со временем пользуйтесь UTC временем.

```js
let diff = new Date(0); // Ваша разница между двумя датами в ms
console.log(diff.getHours()); // 4 часа ночи 1 января 1970 года по мск
console.log(diff.getUTCHours()); // то что надо
```